# Default value for repeatable custom field

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, custom-field, repeatable-field

I am trying to set a default value for the [repeatable custom field](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_custom_fields/Repeatable_Field).
My subform has a number field, a media field and a text field.
I am using the default value field in the repeatable field configuration like this :

[image: repeatble filed subform with default value]

And this is what I tried for the default value :

`"type":"2","Fichier":"images\/blog\/test.jpg","Description":"Default description"`

I am somehow not getting the syntax right or maybe not using the right approach for this.
My aim is to have values already filled with content when adding new subforms while editing the articles here :

[image]

Comment: Can you not use `default="xxxx"` like you'd normally use for form fields?

Comment: @Lodder no, that doesn't work. I tried the value stated in my question because that is what the `rawvalue` element returns when a field has been entered.

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: @Lodder I haven't coded anything in the backend. I am just using custom code to display the field values in a template overide. `default="xxxx"` works fine for the other custom fields (non repeatable text for example)

Comment: It would need to be in json format, try: {"type":"2","Fichier":"images\/blog\/test.jpg","Description":"Default description"}

Comment: @web can this page be progressed to a resolution?  Did you manage to resolve this? Are there any new clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you would need to change it to be json and array based. Here is a rough example I setup as a default field which works as expected:

```
{"test0":{"type":"2","Fichier":"images\/joomla_black.png","Description":"assasa"}}
```

test0 is the in two parts, test is the name of the field and 0 is the field of the repeatable field.

the rest of it you can see matches similarly to what you have.